# Uncaught TypeError: angular2_1.Component is not a function: error on running the application

Tags: gulp

I am a newbie to AngularJS + Asp.net5 + Gulp. tried downloading a sample from the internet and executed it. But I am facing issues while executing the application.

I am getting the below mentioned errors when i Execute after manually placing the required JS/CSS files in the Lib folder.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
angular2-polyfills.js:1152 DEPRECATION WARNING: 'enqueueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use addTask/addRepeatingTask/addMicroTask
:24314/lib/spa/app.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: angular2_1.Component is not a function
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 Uncaught TypeError: angular2_1.Component is not a function
    Evaluating http://localhost:24314/lib/spa/app.js
    Error loading http://localhost:24314/lib/spa/app.js
```

I have placed following code in the app.ts file,

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {provide, Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_BINDINGS, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers, RequestOptions, BaseRequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';

import {
RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_BINDINGS,
Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy
} from 'angular2/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {enableProdMode} from 'angular2/core';

enableProdMode();
import { Routes, APP_ROUTES } from './routes';

import { DataService } from './core/services/dataService';
import { MembershipService } from './core/services/membershipService';
import { UtilityService } from './core/services/utilityService';
import { User } from './core/domain/user';

@Component({
    selector: 'photogallery-app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig(APP_ROUTES)
export class AppRoot {
    private routes = Routes;

    constructor(public membershipService: MembershipService, location: Location) {
        this.routes = Routes;
        location.go('/');
    }

    isUserLoggedIn(): boolean {
        return this.membershipService.isUserAuthenticated();
    }

    getUserName(): string {
        if (this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            var _user = this.membershipService.getLoggedInUser();
            return _user.Username;
        }
        else
            return 'Account';
    }

    logout(): void {
        this.membershipService.logout()
            .subscribe(res => {
                localStorage.removeItem('user');
            },
            error => console.error('Error: ' + error),
            () => { });
    }
}

class AppBaseRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    headers: Headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
}

bootstrap(AppRoot, [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(RequestOptions, { useClass: AppBaseRequestOptions }),
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
    DataService, MembershipService, UtilityService])
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

// ROUTER_BINDINGS: DO NOT USE HERE IF YOU WANT TO HAVE HASHLOCATIONSTRATEGY!!
```

Also the Gulp.js file contains the following code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    merge = require('merge'),
    fs = require("fs"),
    del = require('del'),
    path = require('path');

eval("var project = " + fs.readFileSync("./project.json"));
var lib = "./" + project.webroot + "/lib/";

var paths = {
    npm: './node_modules/',
    tsSource: './wwwroot/app/**/*.ts',
    tsOutput: lib + 'spa/',
    tsDef: lib + 'definitions/',
    jsVendors: lib + 'js',
    jsRxJSVendors: lib + 'js/rxjs',
    cssVendors: lib + 'css',
    imgVendors: lib + 'img',
    fontsVendors: lib + 'fonts'
};


var tsProject = ts.createProject('./wwwroot/tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('setup-vendors', function (done) {
    gulp.src([
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.*.js*',
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js*',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.*',
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.*js',
      'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap*.js',
      'node_modules/fancybox/dist/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js',
      'bower_components/alertify.js/lib/alertify.min.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsVendors));

    gulp.src([
       'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsRxJSVendors));

    gulp.src([
      'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
      'node_modules/fancybox/dist/css/jquery.fancybox.css',
      'bower_components/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
      'bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.core.css',
      'bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.bootstrap.css',
      'bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.default.css'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssVendors));

    gulp.src([
      'node_modules/fancybox/dist/img/blank.gif',
      'node_modules/fancybox/dist/img/fancybox_loading.gif',
      'node_modules/fancybox/dist/img/fancybox_loading@2x.gif',
      'node_modules/fancybox/dist/img/fancybox_overlay.png',
      'node_modules/fancybox/dist/img/fancybox_sprite.png',
      'node_modules/fancybox/dist/img/fancybox_sprite@2x.png'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.imgVendors));

    gulp.src([
      'node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2',
      'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/FontAwesome.otf',
      'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot',
      'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg',
      'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf',
      'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff',
      'bower_components/components-font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2',
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.fontsVendors));
});

gulp.task('compile-typescript', function (done) {
    var tsResult = gulp.src([
       "node_modules/angular2/bundles/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts",
       "node_modules/angular2/bundles/typings/angular2/http.d.ts",
       "node_modules/angular2/bundles/typings/angular2/router.d.ts",
       //"node_modules/@reactivex/rxjs/dist/es6/Rx.d.ts",
       "wwwroot/app/**/*.ts"
    ])
     .pipe(ts(tsProject), undefined, ts.reporter.fullReporter());
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tsOutput));
});

gulp.task('watch.ts', ['compile-typescript'], function () {
    return gulp.watch('wwwroot/app/**/*.ts', ['compile-typescript']);
});

gulp.task('watch', ['watch.ts']);

gulp.task('clean-lib', function () {
    return del([lib]);
});

gulp.task('build-spa', ['setup-vendors', 'compile-typescript']);
```

Can anyone help me on resolving this issues? Please revert back if more informations are required.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As written, you have two parts of a board question. I would suggest breaking your larger question down into two smaller questions.

Comment: as suggested by Richard, i have removed my first question. Please answer my second question.